# JQuery AJAX - passing data from form to PHP script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

My task is triggering php script from HTML form, which is updating JSON file from which HTML is generated. Here is how i am trying to do that. 
HTML Form:

```
<form method="post">
    <label for="board">Board to update:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="board" name="board"><br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="update()">
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function update() {
    var board=$('#board').val();
    $.post('update.php',{boardname:board}, function() {
        alert("update successfull");
    })
}
```

and PHP:

```
<?php

$q=$_POST['boardname'];
echo ($q);
shell_exec('curl https://cyberland.club/' . $q . '/?num=1000 > posts.json');

?>
```

There is no error after clicking button, but website is not updating. Can you tell me why is that? What am i doing wrong? I was using this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVAaxkbmCts

Comment: Have you watched the request/response in the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Do you really need shell_exec?

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld thats how i was doing GET requests so seems straightforward. Script does not work online at the moment, so i dont need to change it for now. PHP script works when $q="o" and run from the command line, so fur sure problem is with passing variable.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard  How to do it?

Comment: Click the F12 key and look for the network tab.

Comment: @JayBlanchard after pressing enter in input field network tab shows File:  tablelocal.html, Cause: document. Do you it should be File: update.php and Cause: xhr?

Comment: Without actually being able to see your developer tools it would be hard to say. Is this coming from the request/response?

Comment: @JayBlanchard after clicking Submit button i see new POST request in network tab with File: update.php Case: xhr Type: octet-type. When i click in this POST request in network tab, browser asks me if i want to download update.php. Is this exxpected behaviour? Is there a way to see update.php output that i see in terminal after clicking button? For example i click button in browser but in terminal i see curl progress bar of downloading file

Comment: so i think browser is making POST request to localhost:8000/update.php every time i click submit button. Maybe i did not defined this POST request? Maybe i should define in update.php if issget($_POST['board']) shell_exec or something like that?

Comment: Yep - you should do that.

Comment: still does not work. My php script now looks like that
if (isset($_POST['boardname'])) {
shell_exec('curl https://cyberland.club/' . $q . '/?num=1000 > posts.json');
}

Comment: So now it wont update if i run it from command line, but stll is doing nothing when run from browser after clicking submit button